# Issue with converting string (25-11-2023 13:33:46+0000) to date in sql server

Tags: datetime, time, type-conversion, datetime-format, date-conversion

i am consuming an API and part of the response is a date value (  25-11-2023 13:33:46+0000  ) that was stored as a string.

I am trying to convert this ( 25-11-2023 13:33:46+0000 ) to datetime or just date in my sql server database and i get the error message in the title.

I have used Cast, Convert and i still get the error when when converting.

cast('25-11-2023 13:33:46+0000' as date)
convert(date, '25-11-2023 13:33:46+0000')

i will appreciate an assitance please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi, why won't you substring your String datetime then cast is to date?

i.e:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING('25-11-2023 13:33:46+0000',0, 11),105)
```

Convert takes date in pattern "yyyy-MM-dd", that's why it is showing an error on converting, or you can add "105" as a parameter which corresponds to the format "dd-MM-yyyy".

[test it][1]

Comment: you are genuis bro, this WORKED !!!

Comment: Thank you, if you please mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to isolate the date this way :

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(column_name, 10))
FROM database_name.table_name;
```

Comment: i tried this, and i still get this error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the times are stored into a table named **times** and a column named **raw_date** containing your initial data, and a column named **date**, empty with date type.

```
update times set date = str_to_date(LEFT(raw_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y');
```

This only keeps the day, month and year with the `LEFT(raw, 10)`... the `str_to_date(..., '%d-%m-%Y)` convert the string into date according to the second argument. It works for me on mariadb.